# Web DriverException: IEDriverServer.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3

Tags: python, internet-explorer, webdriver, robotframework

I'm running automated testing using the following tools
- Robot framework
- Python 2.7

Browser: IE11
OS: Windows 10 - 64 bits

Currently, I run test on VM which has some restriction to install software so I have to package them into one zip file and use some portable software to run the robot framework.

In order to run Python, I have to use command line to add some environment path variable to VM for configuration

---

```
@echo off
title - FRAUD Test Team
set load=
set/a loadnum=0
:Loading
set load=%load%ÛÛ
cls
echo.
echo Starting Robot Framework
echo ----------------------------------------
echo %load%
echo ----------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
if %loadnum%==20 goto Done
goto Loading
:Done
echo.
set PY_HOME=M:\python\App
set PYTHONPATH=M:\python\App
set PATH=%PY_HOME%;%PYTHONPATH%;%ORACLE_HOME%;M:\python\App\Scripts;M:\python\App\webdriver;M:\python\App\Lib\site-packages;M:\python\App\instantclient_11_1;%PATH%
set webdriver.ie.driver=M:\python\App\webdriver\IEDriverServer.exe
echo Environment Variables:
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo %PATH%
cls
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo Robot Framework is ready to use on AVC
echo ----------------------------------------------
cmd /k
```

---

Previously, it works fine then it shows error message as you can see in screen shot.
[error-ie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYsIE.png)

I'm not sure if it's about

1. IE Webdriver
2. Windows 10
3. Permission in my VM

Does anyone has same issue?

Comment: You said "previously it worked, now there's the error message" - do something changed; what changed? :) Was IE updated with a patch, or the ie driver changed, or selenium was upgraded? What's the output - the full stacktrace - when creating a driver session from python's REPL in this environment?

Comment: After contacting support team and spent time to investigate this issue, it happens that there is whitelist software that block the ie webdriver during test execution of robot framework.

Once the whitelist is granted then I can run the robot test smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting support team and spent time to investigate this issue, it happens that there is whitelist software that block the ie webdriver during test execution of robot framework. Once the whitelist is granted then I can run the robot test smoothly.